# Applying jQuery live() to the to dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery

I have following javascript when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.rounded').corner();
});
```

It's a simple jQuery plugin that rounds corners of `DIV` s.

But I also have some dynamically loaded DIVs on my page in which the rounded corners are not being applied. I realise I should use either `live()` or `livequery()` functions, but how would I apply this?

Comment: if you are adding div via ajax you can use `$('.rounded').corner();
` in the `success:`

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is the jQuery `bind()` method. You'll have to update your code that actually appends the `div` in question - but the short of it is that you'll have to call `trigger(youreventcustomname)` on the addition.

Here's an example for your use case:

```
$(function(){

  // the bind call
  $('.rounded').bind('divbox',function(){
    $(this).corner();
  });

  //the dom add
  $('html').append('<div></div>').addClass('rounded').trigger('divbox');
});
```

Some more reading:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#14

Comment: Not quite, his problem is that elements are loaded on the page dynamically by other jquery calls.  Using .bind only binds the event to elements *currently* on the page, not future elements that match the selector.  You have to use .live to attach it to future elements.  But I think your solution will work if he changes .bind to .live.

Comment: guess trigger does the real job

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try

```
 $(div).corner();
```

at the moment they generate.

Comment: that means I have to add $(div).corner() every time they are generated right? I want to have this code in a single place.

Comment: @ebae yes you have to register event after they are generated. If you have event defined before the page are generated, then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it'll help

```
   $('.rounded').livequery(function(){ 
        $(this).corner(); 
    });
```